# Is this factory and how do I make constructor for struct?

Tags: rust

```rs
struct Person{
    name: String
}

fn person_factory(name: String)-> Person {
    Person{
        name,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = person_factory("Viktor Draganov".to_string());

    println!("{}", p1.name);
}
```

Is this factory in rust? And how can I initialize person from constructor?

Comment: Take a look at this documentation https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/ctor.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`person_factory` does look like a factory (if not a particularly useful or necessary one). Usually factories exist to abstract some creation logic away from the user. Such as converting a date of birth to an age when creating a person.

Rust does not have any special method that works like a constructor you'd be familiar with from languages like Java, Python, C++, etc; however, there is a common practice that provides essentially the same behavior as described in this site which covers Rust design patterns: [Constructors](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/ctor.html).

Following this article you could make a "constructor" for your Person class like this (it should look VERY similar to the factory method you shared above):

```rust
struct Person{
    name: String
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Person {
            name: name
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Person::new("Viktor Draganov".to_string());

    println!("{}", p1.name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to have more general aproach you can accept more types for Person with this:

```rust
pub struct Person {
    pub name: String,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new<T>(name: T) -> Self
    where
        T: ToString,
    {
        Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Person::new("Viktor Draganov".to_string());
    let p2 = Person::new(&"Viktor Draganov".to_string());
    let p3 = Person::new(&"Viktor Draganov".to_string()[..]);
    let p4 = Person::new("Viktor Draganov");
    let p5 = Person::new(&"Viktor Draganov");
    let p6 = Person::new(123456789);
    // ... you can use any type that impl's ToString trait so you can call to_string()

    println!("String(owned): {}", p1.name);
    println!("&String(borrowed): {}", p2.name);
    println!("String Slice: {}", p3.name);
    println!("&'static str: {}", p4.name);
    println!("&str: {}", p5.name);
    println!("i32: {}", p6.name);
}
```

furthermore Display trait in standard library is a blanket implementation of ToString trait so you can call to_string() for every type that implements Display trait. We can create a Person from Cat with cats name.

```rust
//.. snip

pub struct Cat {
    pub tag: String,
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Cat {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.tag)
    }
}

fn main() {
    //..snip

    let cat1 = Cat { tag: "Tekir".into() }

    let p7 = Person::new(cat1);

    // ..snip
    println!("from Cat type: {}", p7.name);
}
```